# Outline on the inside, in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a shape in illustrator, an outline of a guitar, and I would like to add an outline on the inside, so as to represent binding. I need it to be around 1mm perfectly aligned along the outside path.

I have attempted this using outline and using scale. Any idea on how to achieve this? Any help would be great, thanks folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use path offset**. Select the path for guitar outline. Go to **Object -> Path -> Offset Path**. For inside offsets, use a negative number.

Comment: That is close, but it is giving me an outline on the outside also. The path is not a complete path, more like an outline with a chunk missing. Is this perhaps what is causing it?

Comment: @moikey I am not sure, it would be easier to see what is going on with an image. If you have an incomplete path, using offset path will create the offset path but will create lines to make a completed path.

Comment: after testing it on a rectangle, it appears that it was because it was not a joined path. I've joined the path and correct it.Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Other option if you don't want to calculate anything:**

Simply duplicate that outline you already have (menu "object", then "transform" then "copy" with the 0 value everywhere)

[image: how to copy in Illustrator]

Then set your outlines to "Align stroke to inside" in the stroke panel.

[image: Align stroke]